# "firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY)" could not make the “Save” menu item active

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my editor, I have below function to set the editor dirty whenever I make some changes in the text widgets within the editor,

```
private void setDirty(boolean b){
        isDirty = b;
        firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY);
    }
```

The issue is that I could see the editor title shown a symbol “*” into dirty state when setDirty(…) is called, but I see the “Save” menu item is still gray(see below snapshot).
[image]

The "Save" menu item is defined by plugin.xml as follows,

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="myProject.file"
               label="File">
            <command
                  commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
                  label="Save"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar
               id="myProject.toolbar1">
            <command
                  commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
                  label="Save"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Could anyone help to see the issue? What's wrong in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you override `isDirty()` in your editor class?  Something like:

```
@Override
public boolean isDirty() {
    return isDirty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to add following codes into ApplicationActionBarAdvisor class, then the Save menuitem could be enabled and my issue is solved,

```
protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        register(ActionFactory.SAVE.create(window));
    }
```

does the "register(...)" must be called?

It is strange that I run my RCP at Eclipse 3.7 without calling register(...), the Save menu item could be enabled by firePropertyChange(). But it doesn't work at eclipse 4.0. Therefore, I created this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call editorDirtyStateChanged() after firing property change.